# Realm очищает базу, при изменении класса

Tags: android, база-данных, realm

Почему при изменении класса БД Realm полностью очищается? То есть был у меня класс 
**Weapon.class**

```
public class Weapon extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int ID;
    private String NameWeapon;

    //Constructor, getters, setters...

}
```

И всё хорошо, данные сохраняются и читаются без проблем, при добавлении новых записей ничего не слетает. Но, например мне нужно изменить класс

```
public class Weapon extends RealmObject {

    @PrimaryKey
    private int ID;
    private String NameWeapon;
    private float Cost = 0f;

    //Constructor, getters, setters...

}
```

Я добавил новую переменную в класс, и если так запустить приложение, то оно вылетит, потому что в БД не будет ничего, Realm не даст считать старые записи. А если заново собрать БД (вставить записи по умолчанию), то потеряются данные, которые были внесены пользователем. Как быть? Не переходить же на SQLite

Comment: Оно автоматом чистит базу при изменении моделей, да. Надо код для миграции писать самостоятельно при каждом изменении модели. С другими БД всё то же самое

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Причина удаления моей БД:

**MyApp.class**

```
mRealmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name(Constants.DATABASE_NAME_REALM)
            .schemaVersion(0)
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .build();
```

Я совсем забыл про этот момент. Я сам дал указание, чтобы БД была очищена (`.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()`) когда потребуется миграция

```
mRealmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
            .name(Constants.DATABASE_NAME_REALM)
            .schemaVersion(0)
            .migration(new Migration())
            .build();
```

**Migration.class**

```
public class Migration implements RealmMigration {

    @Override
    public void migrate(DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {

    RealmSchema mSchema = realm.getSchema();

    /****************************************************************
     * Version 0
     *
        class Weapon
           @PrimaryKey
           private int ID;
           private String NameWeapon;

     *
     * Version 1
     *
         class Weapon
            @PrimaryKey
            private int ID;
            private String NameWeapon;
            private float Cost = 0f;
     ****************************************************************/

    if (oldVersion == 0) {
        RealmObjectSchema mPrimaryCaseSchema = mSchema.get("Weapon");

        mPrimaryCaseSchema
                .addField("Cost");
        oldVersion++;
    }
}
```

Больше информации: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/master/examples/migrationExample/src/main/java/io/realm/examples/realmmigrationexample

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations